# Unrar file with subdirectory

Tags: c#, rar

I have used [NUnrar](http://nunrar.codeplex.com) to extract my files :

```
NUnrar.Archive.RarArchive archive = NUnrar.Archive.RarArchive.Open(location + "1.rar");

foreach (RarArchiveEntry item in archive.Entries)
{
    string path = Path.Combine(location, Path.GetFileName(item.FilePath));
    item.WriteToFile(path);
}
```

If my file has no any sub directory all things works but if rar file has sub directory all of them extracted to same folder how i can keep model of sub directory and file places

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had to do some experimenting to get NUnrar to work properly as well.
Perhaps the little success I had can help you.

```
RarArchive archive = RarArchive.Open(@"D:\Archives\Test.rar");
foreach (RarArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
{
    try
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(entry.FilePath);
        string rootToFile = Path.GetFullPath(entry.FilePath).Replace(fileName, "");

        if (!Directory.Exists(rootToFile))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(rootToFile);
        }

        entry.WriteToFile(rootToFile + fileName, ExtractOptions.ExtractFullPath | ExtractOptions.Overwrite);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //handle your exception here..
    }
}
```

The code I have already uses (Exception e) further up, so I had to use (Exception ex) instead.
It's probably sloppy code, and could do with a tidy up - but being as late as it is I'm inclined to leave it be as it 'works'..

Comment: In the latest version, there is no such field entry.FilePath, use entry.Key instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
NUnrar.Archive.RarArchive.WriteToDirectory("update.rar", Application.StartupPath,NUnrar.Common.ExtractOptions.ExtractFullPath | NUnrar.Common.ExtractOptions.Overwrite);
```

if "update.rar" is inside the same directory as the executable.

Comment: This is the eaysiest way ever ! don´t need to make it as complicated as Frankish did.

Answer (score 0):

[I'd think](http://nunrar.codeplex.com/documentation) `RarArchive.ExtractToDirectory(source, destination);` should work.

Or using your loop, change it to `string path = Path.Combine(location, item.FilePath);`